# Extension method on Item in List within another List

Tags: c#

I'm trying to perform an run an extension method on every item within a `List<>` that is inside another `List<>` to return collection of a given type (returned by the extension method).

I initially tried (and failed) to do this using linq, but I have the following:

```
        var dataset = GetReportDataset(org);

        var reportData = new List<InterventionAndNeetRiskReportLineModel>();

        foreach (var record in dataset)
        {
            foreach (var inter in record.InterventionHistory)
            {
                 reportData.Add(inter.ToInterventionAndNeetRiskReportLineModel());
            }
        }
        return _reportWriter.ReportCsvStream(reportData);
```

So my question is, how can I project the result of my extension method for each item in the child collection using linq?

**UPDATE** `ToInterventionAndNeetRiskReportLineModel()` extension method

```
    public static InterventionAndNeetRiskReportLineModel ToInterventionAndNeetRiskReportLineModel(this InterventionHistory intervention)
    {
        return new InterventionAndNeetRiskReportLineModel()
        {
            Beneficiary = intervention.Person.Beneficiary,
            CourseTitle = intervention.CourseTitle,
            CaseNotes = intervention.CaseNotes,
            EndDate = intervention.EndDate?.ToString(),
            StartDate = intervention.StartDate.ToString(),
            ParticipantId = intervention.Person.ParticipantId,
            FirstEit = intervention.Person.EitScores.GetFirstEitReading().ToString(),
            LastEit = intervention.Person.EitScores.GetLastEitReading().ToString(),
            FirstLpt = intervention.Person.LptScores.GetFirstLptReading().ToString(),
            LastLpt = intervention.Person.LptScores.GetLastLptReading().ToString(),
            Gender = intervention.Person.Equalitites.Gender,
            HoursAttended = intervention.NoOfHours.ToString(),
            LanguageOfDelivery = intervention.DeliveryLanguage,
            Providername = intervention.ProviderName,
            QanCode = intervention.QanCode,
            SchoolCollegeName = intervention.ProviderName
        };
    }
```

Comment: It's not clear what the extension method is, nor what "and failed" means. Please provide a [mcve].

Comment: Are you just trying to find all the elements of a list that are part of another list? You don't need an extension for that.

Comment: Extension method added

Comment: What's the type of `record.InterventionHistory`, and then what is the type of `inter`? You are using `InterventionHistory` both as a collection (`foreach`) and as a flat type (in the extension method). One of the two but not both should be the case. Go easy on the `var` and write out some types to see where you're going wrong.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm not completely sure which part of the question code you want to separate into an extension method. Also, don't be to focused on the extension method part, its nothing different from other functions, as far as the writing is concerned.

You can use `SelectMany` in order to get a flat list of `InterventionHistory` objects and `Select` in order to convert to `InterventionAndNeetRiskReportLineModel` and `ToList` for the final result as list instead of `IEnumerable<T>` if you really need that.

```
var reportData = GetReportDataset(org)
    .SelectMany(r => r.InterventionHistory)
    .Select(i => i.ToInterventionAndNeetRiskReportLineModel())
    .ToList();
```

So, maybe you want an extension method like

```
public static IEnumerable<InterventionAndNeetRiskReportLineModel> ToInterventionRiskReports(this IEnumerable<ReportDataset> _self)
     return _self
        .SelectMany(r => r.InterventionHistory)
        .Select(i => i.ToInterventionAndNeetRiskReportLineModel());
}
```

And use it as

```
var reportData = GetReportDataset(org).ToInterventionRiskReports().ToList();
```

... as I said, its not completely clear, which part you want to refactor into an extension method.

Comment: SelectMany was the solution I was after. Thanks!! My question could have been clearer but appreciate your efforts.